# What is really going on during Backup-SPSite?

Tags: powershell, site-collection, backup, site

Can anyone explain *in detail* what is really going on(under the hood) during exexuting `Backup-SPSite` powershell cmdlet ?

```
Backup-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

Comment: Could you please explain, WHY you want this information? There is a lot of stuff happening on SQL-Server and it's not documented.

Comment: I just try to understand how i can backup and restore programmatically

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to build your own backup-solution programatically. It is not supported to query SharePoint-Databases directly.

There are tons of APIs and methods to code against SharePoint. They also exist for [backing up SharePoint-Sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc264319(v=office.14).aspx). You should make use of them.